# How can I make JNI RegisterNatives callack Java functions have C++ instance scope?

Tags: java, c++, boost, java-native-interface, boost-thread

I have a C++ application that triggers an Akka Actor-based MapReduce system. This I do via a C++ JNI wrapper class `MapReduceBridge` and it works fine taking into account that the Akka Actor and the C++ application threads need to synchronize (shown below). The problem is that with this design I'm forced to have my C++ `MapReduceBridge` class be a singleton and use static variables because the callback methods registered via `RegisterNatives` are global. My question is what's the best way to move into an class instance scope so multiple instances of this C++ `MapReduceBridge` can coexist?

The two Java to C++ callbacks accomplish the following:

- the C++ thread has to wait for the first callback until the Akka-Actor has deployed/installed in all machines the jar containing the MapExecutor and ReduceExecutor.
- the C++ thread has to wait for the second callback until the Akka-Actor completes running the MapReduce so it can access the results.

I use here two callbacks (function callback from Java to C++) using `RegisterNatives`, this is the C++ side:

```
// allow the C++ MapReduceBridge's application thread to wait for the MapReduce system
static boost::mutex mutex_;
static boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock_(mutex_);
static boost::condition_variable callback_condition_;

// callback notification that installation has completed    
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL com_sfoam_hpcmom_mapreduce_bridge_BridgeClient_startupCompletedCallback(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) {
    log_info << "callback 'startup completed' received";
    callback_condition_.notify_one();
}

// callback notification that MapReduce run has completed   
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL com_sfoam_hpcmom_mapreduce_bridge_BridgeClient_runCompletedCallback(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) {
    log_info << "callback 'run completed' received";
    callback_condition_.notify_one();
}

static const JNINativeMethod kCallbackMethods[] = {
      { "startupCompletedCallback", "()V", (void*)&com_sfoam_hpcmom_mapreduce_bridge_BridgeClient_startupCompletedCallback },
      { "runCompletedCallback"    , "()V", (void*)&com_sfoam_hpcmom_mapreduce_bridge_BridgeClient_runCompletedCallback     }
};

MapReduceBridge::MapReduceBridge(std::string env_jar_path) {
    // ... 
    // snippet where the callbacks are registered
    const int methods_size = sizeof(kCallbackMethods) / sizeof(kCallbackMethods[0]);
    env_->RegisterNatives(bridge_class_, kCallbackMethods, methods_size);
    // ... 
}

void MapReduceBridge::run() {
    // get BridgeClient's method run and invoke it
    env_->CallObjectMethod(bridge_instance_, bridge_run_);
    log_info << "run method launched";

    // wait for the callback that 'run' has completed
    callback_condition_.wait(lock_);
}
```

And on the Java side:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public void onReceiveResult(double[] results) {
    this.results = results;
    runCompletedCallback();
}
```

Following this example my goal is to have the synchronization variables `mutex_`, `lock_` and `callback_condition_` not static but a member of my `MapReduceBridge` C++ class and therefore be able to have multiple instances of `MapReduceBridge` i.e. the callbacks should execute not statically but in the scope of my current `MapReduceBridge` instance.

e.g. one possible solution would be to save in Java a pointer to the C++ `this` instance and pass that pointer during the callbacks. How can I do that in JNI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store a c/c++ object's address(i.e. pointer) in your Java class as a long.  When you return the long to your JNI native layer( as a jlong ), just cast it back to your object pointer.

C++

```
// callback notification that MapReduce run has completed   
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL com_sfoam_hpcmom_mapreduce_bridge_BridgeClient_runCompletedCallback(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jlong ptr) {
    log_info << "callback 'run completed' received";
    MapReduceBridge * ptr = (MapReduceBridge *)ptr;
    //Use ptr now to reference your instance variables
    //callback_condition_.notify_one();
}
void MapReduceBridge::run() {
    // get BridgeClient's method run and invoke it
    env_->CallObjectMethod(bridge_instance_, bridge_run_, (long)this );
    log_info << "run method launched";

    // wait for the callback that 'run' has completed
    callback_condition_.wait(lock_);
}
```

Java

```
public void run(long ptr)
{
    this.ptrToMapReduceBridge = ptr;
    //do stuff
}
@Override
public void onReceiveResult(double[] results) {
   this.results = results;
   runCompletedCallback(this.ptrToMapReduceBridge);
```

}

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer, how is this done? can you include simple snippets?

Comment: @GiovanniAzua added an example.  I assumed your bridge_run_ method signature was `public void run()`  Note: This assumes that your created MapReduceBridge class instance stays in scope throughout the life of the Java->run call.